# How can we avoid linkedin security verification page when trying to scrape data using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I have been trying to scrape list of attendees of an event with their names, where they work and located plus their linkedin contact information; I am using Selenium & bs4 libraries of Python, on top of that Chrome as a web browser and the code works fine, however, sometimes linkedin sends me a security verification page and subsequently, my code breaks. Is there a way to avoid linkedin from sending me the security verification page?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the [official LinkedIn API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/), or if you want a premade wrapper around this API, you could use [this](https://github.com/tomquirk/linkedin-api). From there on, you only have to call the api:

```
profile = api.get_profile('billy-g')
```

But this may not be practical for you, since you already spent time building a working web scraper.

Comment: In order to see list of attendees on LinkedIn, first, you have to be an attendee ; which means I had to sign in and be a part of the event before scraping what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the Steps which I took to bypass Security Check By Linkedin.

1. Change your IP address.

The simplest way to change the IP address of your device is to switch to a different network. For example, if you're browsing on your home Wi-Fi connection on your smartphone, you can turn the Wi-Fi setting off and use mobile data.

2. If you can use AI to select the correct image of the cat, it would be great,
   but good luck with that.
3. Another tedious task would be if you can change linkedin ID's after a specific time, this also surpasses the security check.

I still suggest the first one.

Hope it helps.

And Even if you can't change network everytime, you can do following steps to change your ip everytime.

Go to Command Prompt and run it as Administrator

Type "ipconfig /release"

Now,Type "ipconfig /renew"

For more help check:
https://kb.salisbury.edu/display/TSC/Release+and+renew+an+IP+address